# Ng-value on a select, empty option disapears after selecting a value

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat iterates through an array and loads my select options, and one of the options is an empty string, but if i click in on the values the empty option disapears, im not sure why

this is my select

```
<select 
                        class="form-control input-sm" 
                        id="Select7" 
                        name="grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
                        ng-model="itemForm.grossweightmeasurementunitcode" 
                        ng-readonly="itemForm.produtosempesobrutodefinido"
                        ng-required="!itemForm.produtosempesobrutodefinido">
                            <option ng-repeat="unidadepeso in unidadespeso" value="{{unidadepeso.commoncode}}" ng-selected="itemForm.grossweightmeasurementunitcode == unidadepeso.commoncode">{{unidadepeso.sigla}}</option>
                    </select>
```

i did a $scope.unidadespeso.push = ' '; to achieve the empty value, any ideas?

Comment: Try using ng options on your select instead of using ng repeat on the option element

Comment: i think you should push { "commoncode": '', "sigla": '' } into $scope.unidadespeso

Answer (score 0):

**Add empty item to array.**

Following example might help you.
Please comment if you have any doubts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("myapp", []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.selectedItem = { name: 'two', id: 27 };
          $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30 },{ name: 'two', id: 27 },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
          
          var emptyItem = {name: '', id: '' };
          $scope.items.unshift(emptyItem);

      }]);
    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>

  <p> name of selected item is : {{selectedItem.name}} </p>

  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>

</body>

</html>
```